# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() show.blade.php problem

Tags: php, laravel

when i clicked the post block in my cms, the error appears.

Here's the code of PostsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Blog;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Tag;
use App\Category;


class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Post $post) {
        return view('blog.show')->with('post', $post);
    }

    public function category(Category $category) {

        return view('blog.category')
        ->with('category', $category)
        ->with('posts', $category->post()->searched()->simplePaginate(3))
        ->with('categories', Category::all())
        ->with('tags', Tag::all());
    }

    public function tag(Tag $tag) {
        return view('blog.tag')
        ->with('tag', $tag)
        ->with('categories', Category::all())
        ->with('tags', Tag::all())
        ->with('posts', $tag->posts()->searched()->simplePaginate(3));
    }
}
```

here's the code of Post.php Model

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Category;

class Post extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'description', 'content', 'image', 'published_at', 'category_id', 'user_id',
    ];
/**
 * Delete post image from storage
 * HHE
 * @return void
 */
    public function deleteImage() {
       Storage::delete($this->image);
    }

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function tag() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return bool
     */

    public function hasTag($tagId) {
        return in_array($tagId, $this->tags->pluck('id')->toArray());
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function scopeSearched($query) {
        $search = request()->query('search');

        if (!$search) {
            return $query;
        }

        return $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
    }
}
```

Here's the code of show.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.blog')

@section('title')
{{ $post->title }}
@endsection

@section('header')
<header class="header text-white h-fullscreen pb-80" style="background-image: url({{ asset($post->image) }});" data-overlay="9">
    <div class="container text-center">

      <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto align-self-center">

          <p class="opacity-70 text-uppercase small ls-1">
              {{ $post->category->name }}
          </p>
          <h1 class="display-4 mt-7 mb-8">
              {{ $post->title }}
          </h1>
          <p><span class="opacity-70 mr-1">By</span> <a class="text-white" href="#">
          {{ $post->user->name }}
        </a></p>
          <p><img class="avatar avatar-sm" src="{{ Gravatar::src($post->user->email) }}" alt="..."></p>

        </div>

        <div class="col-12 align-self-end text-center">
          <a class="scroll-down-1 scroll-down-white" href="#section-content"><span></span></a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </header><!-- /.header -->
@endsection

@section('content')
<main class="main-content">


    <div class="section" id="section-content">
      <div class="container">

        {!! $post->content !!}

        <div class="row">

            <div class="gap-xy-2 mt-6">
              @foreach($post->tags as $tag)
              <a class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary" href="{{ route('blog.tag', $tag->id) }}">
                  {{ $tag->name }}
              </a>
              @endforeach
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section bg-gray">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">


            <hr>
            <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>


var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = "{{ config('app.url') }}/blog/posts/{{ $post->id }}";  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
this.page.identifier = "$post->id"; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
};

(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://unicare-clinic.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>


          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>



  </main>
@endsection
```

and the error 
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
(View: 
C:\xampp\htdocs\blogcms\resources\views\blog\show.blade.php)

Any help will be appreciated, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any function(method), or property where you define `tags`. 
In your `Post` model you have method `tag`, but you don't have `tags`.

You should define new method or rename this one.

Answer (score 0):

@oggiesutrisna 
I think what you are trying to do getting tags of a particular post. So since in your model post has a relationship with tag
This should solve the issue

```
 <div class="gap-xy-2 mt-6">
          @foreach($post->tags->first() as $tag)
          <a class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary" href="{{ route('blog.tag', $tag->id) }}">
              {{ $tag->name }}
          </a>
          @endforeach
        </div>
```